# Múltiples constructores para una clase abstracta

Tags: php, poo, clase-abstracta

En PHP tengo una clase abstracta que se ve así (simplificada):

```
abstract class MiClase {

    protected $id = "";
    protected $titulo = "";

    function __construct($titulo) {
        $this->id = strtolower($titulo);
        $this->titulo = $titulo;
    }

    abstract function render();
}
```

Y luego una clase hija que hereda de esa:

```
class MiSubClase extends MiClase {
    function __construct($titulo) {
        parent::__construct($titulo);
    }

    function render() {
        echo "$this->id: $this->titulo";
    }
}
```

Quiero añadir un segundo constructor a la clase abstracta en el que además del título se pueda pasar un id, pero en PHP no hay sobrecarga de funciones por parámetros.  Buscando en Internet, encontré una [publicación en Stack Overflow en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1699796/3695983) donde lo que se sugiere es crear una función estática que cree y devuelva una instancia del propio objeto y que haga las funciones de "segundo constructor", algo como esto:

```
static function crea($id, $titulo) {
    $instancia = new self($titulo);
    $this->id = $id;
    return $instancia;
}
```

Ese método funciona bien en clases "normales", pero no funciona con clases abstractas como ésta y recibo el siguiente error cuando hago `$miclase = MiClase::crea("id", "titulo");`:

> Exception: Cannot instantiate abstract class MiClase

que ocurre en la línea donde hago `$instancia = new self("titulo")`, y que tiene sentido porque se estaría intentando instanciar la propia clase que es abstracta, lo cual no está permitido.

¿Cómo se podría entonces crear varios constructores en una clase abstracta en PHP?

Comment: Del [Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.abstract.php): *PHP 5 introduce clases y métodos abstractos. Las clases definidas como abstractas **no se pueden instanciar** y cualquier clase que contiene al menos un método abstracto debe ser definida como tal. Los métodos definidos como abstractos simplemente declaran la firma del método, pero no pueden definir la implementación.* O sea, no puedes, bajo ningún concepto, usar `new` con una clase abstracta.

Comment: Álvaro [esta es la explicación más clara que conozco](https://phpenthusiast.com/object-oriented-php-tutorials/abstract-classes-and-methods) sobre el sentido de las clases abstractas en PHP. Es una pena que el Manual sea tan malo explicando ese concepto, usando por lo demás nombres genéricos en el código de ejemplo. Creo que este tipo de cosas hay que analizarlas desde un problema de la vida real para entenderlas. En tu ejemplo no tiene ningún sentido que la clase tenga un constructor, ni que tenga un método para crear una copia de la misma clase. Las `abstractas` son para otra cosa...

Comment: Claro, ese es el problema que quiero solucionar (o más bien, encontrar una alternativa al mismo).

Comment: No se entiende el problema entonces. Yo respondí más abajo a tu pregunta: *¿Cómo se podría entonces crear varios constructores en una clase abstracta en PHP?*  Dado que tu método se llama `crear`, supongo que lo que querías era crear una nueva instancia de la clase. De esa clase, no es posible crear instancias. Esa clase no debería tener siquiera un constructor. (Mira los ejemplos del Manual, no tienen constructor). Si esto no resuelve tu duda, deberías entonces mostrar el contexto, por ejemplo las clases relacionadas, y lo que quieres hacer realmente.

Comment: Una clase abstracta puede tener un constructor que se llama desde la clase que hereda. Quiero tener varios constructores. Eso se soluciona con el método estático que menciono, pero ese método estático no funciona con clases abstractas porque tiene que llamar al constructor real y me da ese error.

Comment: No Álvaro, creo que estás planteando mal la solución de tu problema. La clase abstracta es para ayudarte con ciertos métodos que no son comunes a algunos de los *hijos* .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una posible solución sería usando [enlaces estáticos en tiempo de ejecución](http://php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php) (*Late Static Bindings*, en inglés). Los enlaces estáticos en tiempo de ejecución se introdujeron a partir de PHP 5.3.0 y pueden usarse para referenciar la clase llamada en un contexto de herencia estática. De la documentación de PHP (énfasis mío):

> De forma más precisa, un enlace estático en tiempo de ejecución funciona almacenando el nombre de clase de la última llamada que no tenga «propagación». **En el caso de llamadas a métodos estáticos, se trata de la clase nombrada explícitamente** (normalmente la que precede al operador ::); en los casos de llamadas a métodos no estáticos, es clase del objeto.

En la sección de comentarios de la documentación de PHP, [mhh1422 expone un ejemplo](http://php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php#114005) parecido al caso de la pregunta, con un método estático usado para crear un *factory method*:

> ```
> <?php
>
> abstract class A{
>
>    static function create(){
>
>        //return new self();  //Fatal error: Cannot instantiate abstract class A
>
>        return new static(); //this is the correct way
>
>    }
>
> }
>
> class B extends A{
> }
>
> $obj=B::create();
> var_dump($obj);
>
> ?>
> ```

Entonces la solución es tan simple como cambiar el `new self($titulo)` por `new static($titulo)`. Con lo que el código quedaría así y ya no se produce el error:

```
static function crea($id, $titulo) {
    $instancia = new static($titulo);
    $this->id = $id;
    return $instancia;
}
```

Que luego se llamaría de este modo desde la clase hija:

```
$obj = MiSubClase::crea($id, $titulo);
```

Comment: ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo de la vida real? Yo sigo sin entender la estructura de tu modelo de datos. En lugar de `class A`, de `class B` ¿podrías indicar un ejemplo donde se aplique esto que dices? Lo de las clases padres/hijas yo lo entiendo como que el padre en su constructor tiene todos los atributos comunes a las clases hijas, y las clases hijas tienen sus métodos propios, que no están en el padre. Yo no termino de entender qué es lo que quieres hacer aquí.

Comment: @A.Cedano una clase Página con dos hijas para páginas “normales” y “reservadas”. Las clases hijas tienen todos los atributos del padre más algunos propios, tienen métodos comunes a la clase padre y otros que deben ser redefinidos (los abstractos del padre) para cada caso.

Comment: Gracias por responder. ¿En qué se diferencia tu modelo [de este](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14273183/5587982) por ejemplo? Aquí hay una clase padre que es `Db`  y varias clases hijas que serían los distintos DBMS. La conexión es común a todas las clases hijas y luego cada clase hija implementa `select` a su modo. Lo que no alcanzo a entender es por qué tiene que haber en el padre partes reservadas a algunas clases hijas. Yo entiendo justo lo contrario, que lo del padre ha de ser para todas las clases hijas. En este caso, *todas las hijas necesitan de la conexión* que posee el padre.

Comment: Sí, se parece a ese ejemplo. No termino de comprender lo de "partes reservadas a algunas clases hijas", el padre en mi caso no tiene nada en particular reservado a ninguna clase hija, lo de los constructores múltiples viene porque en algunos casos puedo tener más información a la hora de crear la hija o no, pero serviría para todas las clases hijas (no sé si es a eso a lo que te refieres).

Comment: Sí, me refiero a eso. Si esto que dices es cierto: *los constructores múltiples viene porque en algunos casos **puedo tener más información a la hora de crear la hija o no, pero serviría para todas las clases hijas***... creo que hay algo muy extraño en tu modelo de datos. ¿Por qué en ese caso no usar algo así como un array *options* para pasar esos atributos que dices que una hija podría o no tener según los casos? Tampoco entiendo mucho cómo sería eso aplicable en la realidad ni por qué tenga que manejarse eso en la clase padre.

Comment: Pasar un array `options` al constructor del padre sería otra opción.

Answer (score 1):

> ¿Cómo se podría entonces crear varios constructores en una clase
>   abstracta en PHP?

La respuesta es simple: **de ninguna manera**. Es más, una clase abstracta no debe tener constructor, porque no es una clase para ser instanciada.

La referencia es muy clara en el [Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.abstract.php):

> PHP 5 introduce clases y métodos abstractos. **Las clases definidas
>   como abstractas no se pueden instanciar** y cualquier clase que
>   contiene al menos un método abstracto debe ser definida como tal. Los
>   métodos definidos como abstractos simplemente declaran la firma del
>   método, pero no pueden definir la implementación.

[Dejo esta referencia](https://phpenthusiast.com/object-oriented-php-tutorials/abstract-classes-and-methods), que ayudará, partiendo de casos de la vida real, a entender el verdadero sentido de las clases abstractas en PHP, y abogo por que exista (si no existe ya), una buena explicación sobre esto en Stackoverflow en español.

Comment: Que una clase sea abstracta y no pueda instanciarse no quiere decir que no deba tener constructor. Ese constructor se llamará cuando la clase hija sea instanciada.

Comment: Una clase abstracta interesará por llegar metodos que vas a implementar en ella. Si te olvidas del constructor quizá el camino te quede más despejado para resolver tu problema. En una clase abstracta no veo que utilidad pueda tener el constructor @AlvaroMontoro.

Comment: La clases hijas van a redefinir los diferentes métodos abstractos, pero el constructor va a ser común a todas. Por eso quiero ponerlo directamente en la clase abstracta y no tener que redefinirlo en cada una de las clases hijas.

Comment: No entiendo realmente tu planteamiento. Quizá sí colocas las diferentes clases se entienda mejor. Parecería como si quieres tratar a la clase abstracta como si fuese la clase padre, @AlvaroMontoro.

Comment: La clase abstracta es la clase padre. Puse un ejemplo de una clase hija en la pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

La sobrecarga como tal no exite en PHP pero podemos emular parte de ella haciendo uso de las funciones [`func_get_args()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.func-get-args.php), [`func_num_args()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.func-num-args.php) y [`call_user_func_array()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.call-user-func-array.php), la idea basicamente es crear un constructor que llame a una u otra función según el número de argumentos

Nuestra clase abstracta

```
<?php
abstract class MiClase {

    protected $id = "";
    protected $titulo = "";

    public function __construct() {
        // obtener los argumentos
        $arg = func_get_args();
        // obtener el numero de argumentos
        $num = func_num_args();
        // comprobar si exite el método en $this
        if (method_exists($this, '__'.$num)) {
            // llamar al método dentro en $this
            call_user_func_array(array($this, '__'.$num), $arg);
        } else {
            throw new Exception('No existe un __construct con este número ('.$num.') de parametros');
        }
    }
    // __construct sin argumentos
    private function __0(){}

    // __construct con un argumento
    private function __1($titulo)
    {
        $this->titulo = $titulo;        
    }

    // __construct con dos argumentos
    private function __2($titulo, $id)
    {
        $this->titulo = $titulo;        
        $this->id = strtolower($id);
    }

    abstract function render();
}
```

Clase que llama `parent::__construct` con un parametro

```
class MiSubClase extends MiClase {
    function __construct($titulo) {
        parent::__construct($titulo);
    }

    function render() {
        echo "$this->id: $this->titulo";
    }
}
```

Clase que llama `parent::__construct` con dos parametros

```
class MiSubClase2 extends MiClase {
    function __construct($titulo, $id) {
        parent::__construct($titulo, $id);
    }

    function render() {
        echo "$this->id: $this->titulo";
    }
}
```

Ejemplo:

```
$obj = new MiSubClase('Título');
$obj->render(); // : Título


$obj2 = new MiSubClase2('Título', 8);
$obj2->render(); // 8: Título

?>
```

De esta forma podemos crear los constructores que necesitemos con el número de parámetros que necesitemos, solo debemos de utilizar el número de parametros para definir el nombre del falso constructor, espero que se entienda la idea.