# PHP 7 creando clase coche , atributos desconocidos

Tags: php, poo, php7

Estoy probando a hacer una **clase Coche en PHP**.

```
<?php 




    class Coche{

        public $marca;
        public $matricula;
        public $km_h_max;
        public $peso;
        public $alto;
        public $largo;
        public $num_ruedas;


        function __construct(){
            $this->$marca = "Desconocida";
            $this->$matricula = "Desconocida";
            $this->$km_h_max = "Desconocido";
            $this->$peso = "Desconocido";
            $this->$alto = "Desconocido";
            $this->$largo = "Desconocido";
            $this->num_ruedas = "Desconocido";
        }
        // function __construct($marca,$matricula,$km_h_max,$peso,$alto,$largo,$num_ruedas){
        //  $this->$marca = $marca;
        //  $this->$matricula = $matricula;
        //  $this->$km_h_max = $km_h_max;
        //  $this->$peso = $peso;
        //  $this->$alto = $alto;
        //  $this->$largo = $largo;
        //  $this->num_ruedas = $num_ruedas;
        // }

        public function mostrarExpecificaciones(){
            echo "MARCA = " . $this->$marca;
            echo "MATRICULA = " .  $this->$matricula;
            echo "KM/H MAX. = " .  $this->$km_h_max . "KM/H";
            echo "PESO = " .  $this->$peso . " KG";
            echo "ALTO = " .  $this->$alto . "METROS";
            echo "LARGO = " .  $this->$largo , "METROS";
            echo "NUM. RUEDAS = " .  $this->$num_ruedas;
        }

    }


 ?>
```

Simplemente la estoy llamando en mi **main.php**:

```
<?php 

    include_once 'Coche.php';


    echo "<h1>MAIN CLASSS</h1>";
    echo "<br>";



    $peugeot = new Coche();

 ?>
```

Me arroja estos errores :

```
Notice: Undefined variable: marca
```

Y asi con **todos**, no solo la **marca**.
Ambos ficheros (`main.php`,`Coche.php`) estan en el mismo directorio.

Comment: Prueba con `$this->marca` en lugar de `$this->$marca`. Parece que te sobra un `$` en (casi) todos los nombres de variables

Comment: Entonces cada vez que ponga `$this` la variable que le sigue no debe tener el dolar (`$`), no ?

Comment: Y no hay alguna forma de tener un constructor **por defecto** y otro **de inicializacion** ?

Comment: Detrás del `->` no necesitas el `$`(al menos en este caso)

Comment: Puedes tener un constructor por defecto que haga lo que necesites en común y luego diferentes  funciones a las que les pasas los parámetros y devuelvan un objeto (creado con `new self()`). Creo que hay otra pregunta sobre el tema en el sitio. Voy a ver si la encuentro.

Comment: De hecho... parece que fui yo el que hizo la pregunta :P... Sé que en mi caso hablo de clases abstractas, pero explico cómo se funcionaría para una clase _normal_: [Múltiples constructores para una clase abstracta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/210461/250)

Comment: De acuerdo, muchas gracias. Ahora hare otra pregunta respecto a herencia de metodos.

Answer (score 1):

Simplemente es que no llamas de forma correcta a los atributos (variables) dentro de tu clase. La sintaxis correcta para llamar a los atributos de una clase debe ser esta:

```
$this->atributo= "valor";
```

En tu caso:

```
$this->marca = "Desconocida";
```

Es decir, no debes llamarlo (pero sí definirlos, cuidado) con el caracter especial "$".